# Azure, DocumentDB, How to return unique results with JOIN

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This is the query:

```
SELECT c.UserId, c.id, c.Items FROM c JOIN items IN c.Items
```

and off course I get back an object of the same User for each of his Items.

Can I group by or narrow the multiple results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is in the works according to [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333963-add-support-for-aggregate-functions-like-count-su), but it's not yet implemented. In the mean time, you can do this client side, in a collection using your own stored procedure or use the [documentdb-lumenize](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize) sproc to do it.